# How do I concatenate names with varying characters in between based on Conditions?

Tags: html, jquery

I'm very *very* new to jQuery and I'm trying to create a query to use that creates a greeting line for use in html that varies depending on whether certain columns are empty

The data looks like this:

| forename (actual) | surname (actual) | forename (actual)_1 | surname (actual)_1 | forename (actual)_2 | surname (actual)_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Smith |  |  |  |  |
| Judith | Jones | Brian | Jones | Ted | Jones |
| Phil | Daniels | Chris | Daniels |  |  |

I would want to return a greeting that looked like this for each line

Dear John Smith
Dear Judith Jones, Brian Jones and Ted Jones
Dear Phil Daniels and Chris Daniels

So basically the code would need to check how many names are present, and put ',' or 'and' between the last two

The code I've created so far is this, based on some old variables used in a program we used pre-javascript

```js
if (sMultipleNames.length >= 1) 
  sMultipleNames3 = record.fields["forename (actual)"] + ' ' + 
    record.fields["surname (actual)"] + ', ' + 
    record.fields["forename (actual)_1"] + ' ' + 
    record.fields["surname (actual)_1"] + ', ' + 
    record.fields["forename (actual)_2"] + ' ' + 
    record.fields["surname (actual)_2"] + ' and ' + 
    record.fields["forename (actual)_3"] + ' ' + 
    record.fields["surname (actual)_3"];
else if (sMultipleNames.length >= 1) 
  sMultipleNames2 = record.fields["forename (actual)"] + ' ' + 
    record.fields["surname (actual)"] + ', ' + 
    record.fields["forename (actual)_1"] + ' ' + 
    record.fields["surname (actual)_1"] + ' and ' + 
    record.fields["forename (actual)_2"] + ' ' + 
    record.fields["surname (actual)_2"];
else if (sMultipleNames.length >= 1) 
  record.fields["forename (actual)"] + ' ' + 
  record.fields["surname (actual)"] + ' and ' + 
  record.fields["forename (actual)_1"] + ' ' + 
  record.fields["surname (actual)_1"];
else(sMultipleNames) 
  record.fields["forename (actual)"] + ' ' + 
  record.fields["surname (actual)"]
}
```

But I have no idea how to execute it all in one query!

Apologies if this is an incredible easy query, I've tried w3 and other stack overflow posts but they are either way more complicated than I think I need, or I just can't parse the examples into my own requirements!

There could also be more names in the data, up to 10, so if there was a way of doing it ad infinitum that'd be great. I presume it can be done with a switch but I've no idea what the initial expression should be, perhaps a way of checking whether cells are empty and returning the greeting based on that?

Comment: What does the name data look like in JS? Do you have an array of names? Or an object with properties?

Comment: Also do you have the flexibility to change the input data? Adding numbers onto the end of a field name is generally a clue you need a collection type...

Comment: Do you have control over the format of the `records` array of objects? It would be ***much*** simpler if you can amend that to give you a consistent forename/surname keyname pair - ie. without the `_N` appended to each

Comment: This is being used within a program that has a datamapper, that we put a csv into and map onto the columns. The columns come with those names when exported from a program we regularly use so I'd ideally like to make it using those particular column headers for ease of use for future exports.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `sMultipleNames` actually is.

Assume `sMultipleNames` is the number of names;

Try this for loop

```js
let ans = record.fields["forename (actual)"] + ' ' + record.fields["surname (actual)"]
for (let i = 1; i < sMultipleName; ++i ) {
    if (i === sMultipleName - 1) {
        ans = ans + ', ' + record.fields[`forename (actual)_${i}`] + ' ' + record.fields[`surname (actual)_${i}`];
    } else {
        ans = ans + ' and' + record.fields[`forename (actual)_${i}`] + ' ' + record.fields[`surname (actual)_${i}`];
    }
}
```

```
the usage `string` is called template strings
```

you can check it here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: thanks for this! I think my question is poor due to my lack of knowledge. I want sMultipleNames to be the output of the code so that I could then use

```query('#MultipleNames').html(sMultipleNames);```

in my html to return the result...

Comment: I basically also don't think I've done that correctly. I also need to work out how to work out the number of names...

Comment: It seems that you are coding jQuery?

Comment: Perhaps...forgive my absolute ignorance! I did tag it jQuery but aware I say JavaScript in my comment!

Comment: It's bettor to provide the dom structure of #MultipleNames (it means html part)

Comment: Apologies, do you mean the section of html where I want the result of the query to appear?

That is just ```<td id="MultipleNames""></td>```

Comment: In your table, you could get children array by using `document.getElementById('MultipleNames').children` and its length is `document.getElementById('MultipleNames').children.length`. Does it help?

Comment: Sorry TropicsCold, in your original answer you've said 'Assuming sMultipleNames is the number of names', I've realised what you mean but I don't actually have the code for that.

How would I count the number of names in any given row using jQuery?

I assume it'd look like:

```var sMultipleNames = code here```

so I think that is obviously the step I'm missing

Comment: It seems that you have to detect the count of names from html table, so using the array from `document.getElementById('MultipleNames').children` with a for loop to iterate it. Surveying the dom tree, check the if the columns have values then output `sMultipleNames`

Here I said may be abstract, if you can provide more detailed html table, it will be helpful.